# kinit in bash script don't work with php exec function

Tags: php, bash, kerberos, freeipa

I have a problem that I have not been able to solve for several weeks.
I created a registration page that uses the php language to put the user, password and other elements in the database.
I use freeipa for kerberos authentication/LDAP/NTP.

I just want to create the user in freeipa after the registration in the database

For that i launch a bash script with the exec function of php when a user signs up after all the verifications and the capcha ....
This bash script is very simple and chmod is 700 with the owner root:

```
#!/bin/bash
username="$1"
kinit -k -t /tmp/keytab manageuser@MYDOMAIN

ipa user-add $username --first $username --last $username --homedir /app/$username --shell /usr/sbin/nologin
```

My keytab:

```
-rw------- 1 root root  160 mai   20 17:19 keytab
```

I launch this bash script in php

```
$cmd = "sudo ../script $username";
exec($cmd, $output);
print_r($output);
```

Of course the apache user is in the sudoer file for only this script

I created a user "**manageuser**" in FREEIPA with the **manage user's role**, in order to create the users.

This script **works when I run in a terminal**, and the user is created in freeipa but when **the exec function of php launches the script it does not create the user**.

I have the impression that **kinit does not work with php exec** function, why ?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Unrelated to the problem: even if you validate in php the arbitrary input provided by the user, you shall nevertheless escape it: `$cmd = "sudo ../script " .  escapeshellarg($username);`. And in the shell script you must also double-quote all the `"$username"` expansions.

Comment: I didn't put all my php code but indeed I already escape the variables, but you are right, an additional security is not negligible and your remark about the quotation marks around the variable is very relevant thank you

Comment: Did you try with an absolute path `sudo /path/to/script` instead of a relative one `sudo ../script`?